# Loop Error including strings and variables

Tags: c#, web, webclient

I keep getting an error like when I have string, it says it cannot convert 'byte[]' to string. And when I have it as var it says the same thing but gives me an error to the data next to Results.txt.

```
if (Lock.Contains("Mode: Data Grabber"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Loading Data Grabber 2.0! Mode = Data Grabber!\n");
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the websites url!\n");
    Console.WriteLine("(\n) " + "(\n)");
    if (Option == Option)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string data = wc.DownloadData(Option);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading data from " + data);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        if (!File.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"/Results.txt"))
        {
            File.Create(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"/Results.txt");
        }

        File.WriteAllText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"/Results.txt", data);
        Console.WriteLine("All data has been sent to the path");
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the actual problem (use DownloadString instead of DownloadData), but the `if (Option == Option)` looks a bit weird.

Comment: Be aware that `GetCurrentDirectory` can change while your program runs, and that non-admins cannot write to the application directory. Consult [Error about finding the file ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52546595/22437).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write `string` when you have a `byte[]`, i.e., `data`

```
string data = wc.DownloadData(Option);
```

[WebClient.DownloadData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloaddata?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns a `byte[]`

```
public byte[] DownloadData (string address);
```

Try out:

```
string data = wc.DownloadString (address);
```

Comment: So is there a way to fix or edit it, to make it work?

Comment: What are you downloading and from where? If you are trying to crawl through the web and doing web scrapping then use https://html-agility-pack.net/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

Replace this code `string data = wc.DownloadData(Option);` with `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(wc.DownloadData(Option))`

The premise is that the encoding of the corresponding text is UTF-8.

Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the 'DownloadString' method of WebClient to get a string:

```
string data = wc.DownloadString (Option);
```

Now the content will a string.